# why is jquery first().clone() in a table still cloning multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to duplicate a table row and append to my table based on user entry of 1 to 10. Based on the input, I would like to append that many rows to my table.. Here is my current **for loop**. When I run this code and test, jQuery is cloning an exponential number of rows and appending. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$(".RosterCountSelect").change(function(){
   var numOfPlayers = this.value;
   for (var i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++){
       $(".PlayerRow").clone().first().insertAfter(".PlayerRow");
   }
});
```

And here is the **HTML markup.**

```
 <form id="PlayerInfo">
  <table>
   <tr class = "PlayerRow">
    <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Player Full Name" /></td>
    <td><input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Player Number" /></td>
    <td>   <input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Jersey Size" /></td>
    <td>    <input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Short Size" /></td>
    <td>  <input class="teamInput" type="text" placeholder="Male/Female" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: you are cloning, then recloning the clone in the loop, thats why you have multiples

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where I left out each of those bits of info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, after looking at your javascript, I realized you had clone and first backwards. Then I also realized that you were adding on whatever the selected number was, so if you selected 4, you'd add on 4, even though there was already 1 row. So total of 5. I also realized that  you were adding onto every row that had the class PlayerRow, making multiple inserts.

So, I altered your code and now your Javascript looks like this:

```
$(".RosterCountSelect").change(function(){
   var numOfPlayers = this.value;
   c=$('.PlayerRow').length; //How many rows are already shown?
   for (var i = c; i < numOfPlayers; i++){ 
       $(".PlayerRow").first().clone().insertAfter(".PlayerRow:last"); //Cloning only after the LAST one, before it would clone for every row you had with the class PlayerRow.
   }
});
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/tu35mpnc/2/

Answer (score 1):

The duplication is due to [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) when you provide an argument that matches multiple elements.

In that case, it will `.clone()` again in order to insert your clone after each of matched elements.

> 1 intended clone * 5 existing rows = 5 new clones inserted

You'll want to modify the selector to match only one element to insert after, e.g. with [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

```
$(".PlayerRow").clone().first().insertAfter(".PlayerRow:last");
```

---

Also, though it doesn't contribute to the duplication, the order you have `.clone()` and `.first()` being called is wasteful. It creates clones of every existing row, then discards all but the first.

It's more efficient to reduce the size of the collection before cloning:

```
$(".PlayerRow").first().clone().insertAfter(".PlayerRow:last");
```